# Windows update failed (August 2012)

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

My Winodws 7 Pro x64 keeps trying to install updates and every time it says that the update failed. It already restared twice automatically at night, and I also tried to install them manually once. It's running on a ThinkPad T400. Here is the log:
[image]

The error code is `80071A90`

The question is whether others are experiencing this too and if there is a solution. Updates usually work fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has just worked for me:

1. Download and install update "Windows6.1-KB2647753-v2-x64" manually from
   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29156
2. Do a normal Windows update for the remaining files.

Source: http://www.sevenforums.com/windows-updates-activation/247035-windows-update-error-code-80071a90.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

According to the informations from Microsoft error `80071A90` is caused by locked files.

There is a fix-it tool that may correct this problem:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Windows-Update-error-80071A90

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem where I had 6 updates recommended. I tried updating a number of times without success. I then tried doing one update at a time. I had to restart 6 times, but it worked.